# end parameter in echo for Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

## Python has `end` parameter in print()

```
print("You" , end = '@') 
print("Need2LearnAlot")
```

*Will output* --> You@Need2LearnAlot

*Does Nim's echo has this kind of parameter?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your own echo procedure, to do so.

```
proc print(args: varargs[string, `$`], `end`: string = "\n") =
    for arg in args:
        stdout.write(arg)
    stdout.write(`end`)

print 1, 2, 3, `end` = "\n===\n"
```

Note that end in Nim is a special identifier, so you must escape it like that.
More about varargs: https://nim-by-example.github.io/varargs/